# How do I unlock an iPad without giving away password?

Tags: ios

Imagine the following situation:

Person A used his apple icloud information (mail and password) on iPad A.

Person A gave his account to person B.

Person B used this apple account on iPad B.

Person A changed the password and removed iPad B from the apple icloud
account.

Person B can no longer use iPad B as he is constantly being asked to enter the password for the icloud account.

Can person A "unlock" / remove his account from iPad B without giving  the new password to person B and without having iPad B physically and doing it on his own?

Comment: Person B should be able to just remove the iCloud account in Settings.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I'm assuming this question comes about because you have enabled "Find My" on iPad B, and person B is now faced with an iPad that is "Activated Locked" to that iCloud account.

In this case, it is possible to remotely remove the device from your account. First, I would suggest person B should simply try logging off the iCloud account in Settings (i.e. if there's no "Activation Lock" and "Find My" is already disabled).

The next you can try is for person A to remove the device from his/her iCloud account:

1. Ask person B to turn off iPad B
2. Person A needs to logon to iCloud.com in a browser
3. In "Find My" click All Devices and select iPad B
4. Click "Remove from Account".

This will only work if the device is not activation locked.

If the device is activation locked, you can still remove your account remotely:

1. Person A needs to logon to iCloud.com in a browser
2. In "Find My" click All Devices and select iPad B
3. Click "Erase iPad"'
4. Wait until person A receives an email stating that the device has been erased
5. On iCloud.com in the browser, go to "Find My", then "All Devices", select iPad B and click "Remove from Account".

In this manner, you cannot remove the activation lock without erasing the device.

Answer (score 0):

Skip to part 2 to get straight to the nitty gritty.

### Don't share accounts.

> Person A gave his account to person B.

A common misconception because people often think Apple accounts are tied *to the device* and Apple's language during setup encourages this misconception.  Actually, accounts are tied *to the human*.

So this was a violation of the Terms of Service.  One of the many punishments for doing so is this kind of mess. (or to be more precise, Apple's unwillingness to help with it.  By their logic, the account now may have private data for both A and B, and in order to protect A from B and B from A, Apple's best interest is to nuke the account for TOS violation.)

So you will need to sort this out without Apple.

Also keep in mind, **this looks stolen**. From Apple's perspective, Person A bought iPad B and person B stole it.  *Apple very strongly desires **to brick** iPad B, because they are trying to create a cultural understanding that stealing iPads never works, you never get a usable iPad and possessing one will only let the police track you. As such, all of Apple's interests are to thwart person B absolutely*.

### Separating

> Can person A "unlock" / remove his account from iPad B without giving the new password to person B and without having iPad B physically and doing it on his own?

I'm sorry, no, that is not possible.  Person A should not give their password to person B again.  However, *since this is Person A's fault for sharing account info*, they are honor-bound to help Person B resolve it, as follows.

- Person B must bring the iPad to person A.  - Then, Person A must log into the device with their private password.
- Person A may allow Person B to use the iPad to export any data, both off the iPad itself, and also off Apple servers from Account A.  Or not.
- There's more than one Cloud.  Many app makers actually store your data on *their* cloud not Apple's.  For instance games like Hearthstone or Diablo:Immortal, your game progression is on Blizzard (Battle.Net) servers not Apple's. Adobe's stuff is on Adobe servers. Etc. Etc.  However, you notice on the Web how you can set up an account to use your Facebook account to log in, so you don't need to setup an email/password login? The same thing can happen in Apps, and with the Apple account (almost by default, really).  So for each app, Person B should go into the app, and see if they can set up an email address and password for that "app account" e.g. Blizzard or Adobe. Doing so will disconnect it from Person A's Apple account and require email/password to log in to that app. (it would pay for person B to research this in advance).
- When person B is done with data export, should give iPad B to person A.
- Person A must then [wipe the iPad entirely](https://support.apple.com/guide/ipad/erase-ipad-ipad8f91b5e3/ipados). (Settings -> General -> Transfer -> Erase All.)
- Then Person A gives iPad B back to person B who owns it.

Person B will now have a "fresh out of the shrinkwrap" new iPad which person B can set up with an Apple account of their very own.  Note that if Person B already has their own Apple account, a very common blunder when setting up an iPad is to accidentally create *another one*.

Apple encourages this with bad choice of language in setup screens.  Apple NEVER allows account merges. (Honestly, I wonder if Apple does this on purpose to make people re-buy apps and music).

This "Brand new iPad" won't have any apps on it. Person B can go to the App Store and buy all the apps they want.

Now remember that thing about setting email/password earlier?  OK, when Person B is starting up those apps, they should log into the Blizzard, Adobe, etc. accounts with the email/password they did set up.  That should bring their cloud data onto their new iPad - sorry their iPad now using THEIR Apple account. I've done this, and it works.

### Why care?

Why should Person A help Person B? After all, Person B loses and person A is not affected, *right?*  HAHA.  Remember what I said about Apple's interests here? If A does not help B, B is likely to go ask Apple for help. When Apple hears that story they're as likely to *nuke the account from orbit* due to the inability to protect either person's data from the other person. (and clearly A and B are adversaries since they have not cooperated to resolve this privately).

B has already lost everything so they have nothing to lose.  *But they can make Person A also lose*.

There's also an outside chance person B could convince them that the account has been theirs all along, and Person A hacked it.

Answer (score -2):

You must use a computer to put your iPad in recovery mode if you can't recall your passcode when you try again. Your data and settings, including your passcode, are deleted throughout this process, allowing you to re-setup your iPad.

You may restore your data and settings from a backup after wiping your iPad. You can set up your iPad as a new device and download whatever iCloud data you have if you didn't back it up.

Comment: The question was not about a forgotten pass code, but a person not having the iCloud password. Two very different things.

Comment: This does not answer the OP's question at all...

Answer (score -3):

I know this will be an unpopular answer, but person A could give their new icloud password to person B so that they can sign out of the icloud on that device and then person A could change their password so that person B no longer has access to the account.

Comment: The question specifically said "without giving the new password to person B", so this doesn't answer the question.